# Can we see the kernel source code for Windows 7?

Tags: windows, operating-system, kernel

I study on entropy source using the Random number generator.

So I want to see a kernel source code.

However, I don't exactly know this, and i know this is not known.

Would you tell me about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Driver Foundation forbids such actions due to obvious malicious stuff that can happen if the source code leaks

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to enough information about the device you're using, you could try writing a skeleton driver. However, some TRNGs have open-source driver code, so if yours is one of them, you could download that. If those aren't options in your case, unfortunately proprietary software companies do not generally share their source code (though Microsoft does share their code with certain CS departments in academia - if you're affiliated with one, you could look into that).